# Google Coral USB Accelerator and RPi 3b+ Cant seem to run

Tags: raspberry-pi, google-coral

I have managed to fix the issues of the install but now face a different issue of linking the instalation to my virtual environment. 
This is what it is giving me

```html
(cv) pi@raspberrypi:~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages $ ls -s ~/Projects/python-tflite-source/edgetpu edgetpu
ls: cannot access 'edgetpu': No such file or directory
/home/pi/Projects/python-tflite-source/edgetpu:
total 40
4 basic  4 classification  4 demo  4 detection  4 __init__.py  4 learn  4 __pycache__  4 swig  4 test_data  4 utils
(cv) pi@raspberrypi:~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages $ sudo ls -s ~/Projects/python-tflite-source/edgetpu edgetpu
ls: cannot access 'edgetpu': No such file or directory
/home/pi/Projects/python-tflite-source/edgetpu:
total 40
4 basic  4 classification  4 demo  4 detection 4 __init__.py  4 learn 4 __pycache__  4 swig  4 test_data  4 utils
(cv) pi@raspberrypi:~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages $ sudo ls -s ~/Projects/python-tflite-source/edgetpu 
total 40
4 basic  4 classification  4 demo  4 detection 4 __init__.py  4 learn 4 __pycache__  4 swig  4 test_data  4 utils
(cv) pi@raspberrypi:~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages $ python 
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 05:39:12) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import edgetpu
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'edgetpu'
```

I am following this blog and it still does not seem to work right

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/04/22/getting-started-with-google-corals-tpu-usb-accelerator/

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found a workaround getting it installed on a 3b+ model. 
so you have to install it in the

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/edgetpu
```

and then in your virtual environment you can then make the synth link. I cant make it from a desktop installation or from the download folder apparently.

this is what I used

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages $ ln -s /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/edgetpu edgetpu
```